# Can't make my script supply scheme when in need

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to make use of different `domain names` in order to parse `titles` from them. My current attempt throws the following error which is obvious:

```
raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'Titanrestoration.Ca': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://Titanrestoration.Ca?
```

My try so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    'Titanrestoration.Ca',
    'Campbellroofing.Ca',
    'Bjmillairebuilders.Ca',
    'Rtroofing.Ca'
    ]

for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    print(soup.title)
```

> ***How can I make my script supply schemes if need be?***

Comment: No schema means you haven't supplied `http://` or `https://`. If you know it, i don't understand where is the problem? You need to have complete links, like `https://titanrestoration.ca`

Comment: I have thousands of such domain names and there are two types of schemes `http://` and `https://`. Which one I should go for automatically? Do you understand where is the problem now @Tan_007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We missed the basic point here. A domain name has nothing to do with protocol. Doesn't matter http or https the domain name redirects to the actual site regardless.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    'Titanrestoration.Ca',
    'Campbellroofing.Ca',
    'Bjmillairebuilders.Ca',
    'Rtroofing.Ca'
]

for link in links:
    link = "http://" + link
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    print(soup.title)
```

If you have schema already concatenated to some of the domain names, you should consider stripping the schema and concatenate again.

```
for link in links:
    link = link.strip("http://")
    link = "http://" + link
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    print(soup.title)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tan_007 for your answer. It makes sense now.